# Django+Celery integration with periodic tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am a bit confused on how to configure Django+Celery.
I have followed what is reported in [this guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).
Here it is the bunch of configuration I have to write:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://...'

queue_arguments = {'x-max-length': 1}
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('queue1', routing_key='queue1', queue_arguments=queue_arguments),
    Queue('queue2', routing_key='queue2', queue_arguments=queue_arguments))

from datetime import timedelta
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task1': {
        'task': 'MyProject.tasks.this_is_task_1',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1)
    },
    'task2': {
        'task': 'MyProject.tasks.this_is_task_2',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1)
    }
}


CELERY_ROUTES = {
        'MyProject.tasks.this_is_task_1': {
            'queue': 'queue1',
            'routing_key': 'queue1',
        },
        'MyProject.tasks.this_is_task_2': {
            'queue': 'queue2',
            'routing_key': 'queue2',
        }
}

app = Celery('MyProject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')
app = Celery('MyProject')

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=30,
    CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True,
)

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Based on [1](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), I should put:

1. The tasks in MyProject/tasks.py
2. The 'app' variable creation and initialization in MyProject/celery.py
3. The configuration variables in MyProject/settings.py

If I do so, i receive the following:

```
Couldn't apply scheduled task check_block_height: Queue.declare: (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-length'for queue 'queue2' in vhost '...': received the value '1' of type 'signedint' but current is none
[2015-11-04 00:30:12,899: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up now.
```

It behaves as if the queue has already been created, but without any option.

If I keep just **CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE** and **CELERY_ROUTES** in `settings.py`, everything seems to be working. The truth is that the queue configuration is ignored, that is, the **CELERY_QUEUE** configuration is not used.

Thanks

Comment: I think `tasks.py` should be in Apps directory(Your project's local app)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ruddra. Indeed, it's already there.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do? It would be helpful if you could give a directory structure of your project and app, where you are trying to use celery.

Comment: The directory structure is the one described in the attached link. What I am trying to do is run periodic tasks using celery + django. In addition to that, I am trying to limit the size of the queues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The issue was related to the fact that I already had created the queues, which were not limited.
By deleting them and restarting, everything worked perfectly by putting:
1. all the configuration in settings.py
2. all the Celery creation in celery.py